# Paired difference test

Tags: statistical-significance, model-comparison, paired-comparisons

I am predicting missing values by using two different methods (e.g., data imputation methods). Following I am interested to test if the predicted values, obtained by means of two different methods, are significantly different. The missing values are not normally distributed and lay in the range between 0 and 1. What method should I use?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Do you mean the  values after imputation? Do the non-missing values also have this range?

Comment: Yes, I mean the values after imputation. And, yes, the values of all data in the range of [0,1]

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the degree of non-normality and your sample size, you could probably get away with using a paired t-test to test whether the values obtained by the two methods are significantly different.  The paired t-test is robust to the normality assumption. Alternatively, you could use the Wilcoxon signed-rank test.